# Mailchimp is not receiving firstname and last name

Tags: javascript, php, api, mailchimp

I'm using Mailchimp api to automatically populate a list.

```
<label class="ime"> </label>
<input class="subscriberequiredField subscribename" id="subscribename" type="text" value="Ime">
<label class="prezime"> </label>
<input class="subscriberequiredField subscribelastname" id="subscribelastname" type="type" value="Prezime">
<label class="mail"> E-mail</label>
<input class="subscriberequiredField subscribeemail" id="subscribeemail" name="subscribeemail" type="text" value="Email">
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE">
```

API:

```
<?php

    require_once 'mailchimp/inc/MCAPI.class.php';
    // MailChimp API Key
    // MailChimp API Key ARTICLE at http://kb.mailchimp.com/accounts/management/about-api-keys#Finding-or-generating-your-API-key
    $api = new MCAPI('api-key-is-here');
    $merge_vars = array();

    // MailChimp List IDb 
    // MailChimp List ID ARTICLE at http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/managing-subscribers/find-your-list-id
    $retval = $api->listSubscribe( 'list-id-is-here', $_POST["subscribeemail"], $_POST["subscribename"], $_POST["subscribelastname"], $merge_vars, 'html', false, true );

?>
```

For some reason the $_POST["subscribename"] and $_POST["subscribelastname"] are not getting through to the list. The API Key and List ID is correct.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put it in input name. Currently you have it only as class and id.

For example:

```
<input class="subscriberequiredField subscribename" name="subscribename" id="subscribename" type="text" value="Ime">

<input class="subscriberequiredField subscribelastname" name="subscribelastname" id="subscribelastname" type="type" value="Prezime">
```

Comment: And the $_POST logic is okay?

Comment: As I can see you are using MCAPI-PHP so if you follow it's guide it should work. If you get email then it is fine.

Comment: I've tried now again. But the list isn't populating. What would be delay if there is any?

Comment: Try with this example from official github page https://github.com/jbrooksuk/MCAPI-PHP/blob/master/examples/mcapi_listSubscribe.php

Comment: I'm not really experienced with php, could you please edit your answer with the PHP part? Thanks.

Comment: You have all you need in that example. I can't do much more. Just change `$merge_vars` with your post data. Also have in mind that you will not see subscriptions in list until it is confirmed in confirmation mail.